# Error while defining a class method outside the class body

Tags: c++, class, header-files

The compiler is throwing up an error with my function `vecListAtt connFrFile(int file_ext);` in a class, and I have no idea why. The error says

"Error: declaration is incompatible with "vecListAtt neighborAtt::connFrFile(int file_ext)" (declared at connectivity.h)"

connectivity.h:

```
#if !def connectivity_H
#define connectivity_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

class listAtt;
class vecListAtt;

class neighborAtt
{
public:
    neighborAtt(); //default constructor
    neighborAtt(int neighbor_id, int att_1, int att_2);


    vecListAtt connFrFile(int file_ext);
    vecListAtt makeList(std::vector<std::list<neighborAtt>> nodeAndInfo, int nodeID, neighborAtt neighAndAtt);  
    neighborAtt getAtt(std::string currentLine);

private:
    int neighborID;
    int attribute1;
    int attribute2;
};

typedef std::list<neighborAtt> listAtt;
typedef std::vector<listAtt> vecListAtt;

#endif
```

in connectivity.cpp, I define

```
vecListAtt neighborAtt::connFrFile(int file_ext)
{

    vecListAtt node_and_info;

    return node_and_info;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first problem in your code is during the `class neighborAtt` definition.
If a class is forward declared such as:

```
class vecListAtt;
```

Then only a pointer or reference of that class can be used in that context.

```
class neighborAtt {
  vecListAtt connFrFile(int file_ext);
//^^^^^^^^^^ should be pointer or reference
};
```

Once you change it, all the errors would go away. The other alternative is of including the header file which contains `vecListAtt`.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
vecListAtt connFrFile(int file_ext);
```

to

```
vecListAtt *connFrFile(int file_ext);
```

or include the header file for `vecListAtt`

Answer (score 0):

While creating neighborAtt class compiler need to know how much space you going to take for this class. Now in your implementation compiler will require size of vecListAtt  object to compute size of neighborAtt  object so only forward declaration of vecListAtt will not work here. Either your define complete vecListAtt  class or change your neighborAtt  class that can have pointer of vecListAtt . Compiler knows how much size a pointer of vecListAtt  can take.